# SSRS 2008 - Header on report is not showing Dynamic Data

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I have a personel report that is sorted by department name, yet when I add the field for the department name into the header, it only prints out the first department name correctly.  every other page has the header, but still has the initial department name in the header instead of the correct department name.  In other words, the field reference to the department name that is in the header of the report does not update.  I browsed the data that is uses from a stored procedure and the department names are in the data and they are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this is the answer that OP ended using and was **his entire idea**, I'm just posting it because op doesn't currently have enough reputation to do it himself:

"Ok, Here is the solution: I had to add another column to the tablix and add a textbox within it which holds the Department name. Then I hid the column from the report, and set a reference to that textbox within header. The name of the textbox within the tablix was named `DepartmentName` so within the header, I added a textbox with the expression `=ReportItems!DepartmentName1.Value`. Works like a charm!!! "

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that after you add the field for the department name into your header (which I assume is a Textbox), the expression for that textbox is not `first(Fields!DepartmentName.Value,"Your Dataset")` or any other gropuing function. It should be just `Fields!DepartmentName.Value`, assuming that the header is inside a List.

Comment: Sorry Lamak, but I get the error "Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope"  The field is in my dataset.  Also, I added the field to the body of my report and its not updating there either, same problem; it prints the first department name, but uses the same department for all of the report even though there are multiple departments in the dataset

Comment: @user1127973 - If you want to show a different department name on different pages, then you need to put the textbox inside the same list that you are using to create the page breaks, otherwise its gonna show just one name

Comment: Ok, Here is the solution: I had to add another column to the tablix and add a textbox within it which holds the Department name. Then I hid the column from the report, and set a reference to that textbox within header. The name of the textbox within the tablix was named "DepartmentName" so within the header, I added a textbox with the expression "=ReportItems!DepartmentName1.Value". Works like a charm!!!

Thanks for the help... you got me going in the right direction :)

Comment: Hey Lamak, I tried to answer this post, but I dont have enough points to do so.  Can you copy and paste my answer as your answer for me so that if someone else has this issue, they can see it?  thanks

Comment: @user1127973 - That's a nice thing to do, but it would give me an unfair accepted answer. In any case, I'll do it for now, but I encourage you to asnwer it yourself when you have the reputation.